# Redirecting issue in firefox browser

Tags: firefox, redirect

I have been using firefox on ubuntu 22 for more than a month and everything was working fine untill 4 days earlier when i first got error relating to security certificate issue and data hijacking. But i have been using same sites earlier too without any issue. Also those sites are just articles on site without any personal information. From last 2 days i am also getting redirecting issues. First site to redirect to during google search is bestbonusprize.life then if i disable adblocker it just keep redirecting. I don't have any issue accessing same site in google chrome. I switched wifi too but same problem continues for firefox. I just have firefox installed till 4 days earlier, but when i start getting issues i installed chrome to test if i am getting same issue but all work good in chrome.

I try disabling extension in firefox but same issue continues.

I tried using anti-malware but malwarebyte is only available for window and I don't know any thing about anti-virus and malware removal for ubuntu as never needed it.

Please guide me for securing my firefox browser.

I have attached redirected page screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Update :- I uninstall and reinstall firefox. Issue still there for one wifi network. Although if i connect my phone to same wifi and then use my phone's hotspot to access internet in my laptop without using mobile data, it work just fine. I am kind of puzzled because if issue is in wifi, why it work fine indirectly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have written full description of the problem. What else i am suposed to write?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure all you need to do is "Refresh Firefox".

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings

```
Refresh Firefox
1. Click the menu button, click Help and select More Troubleshooting Information.

2. Click Refresh Firefox… then Refresh Firefox in the confirmation window that opens. Firefox will close to refresh itself.

3. When finished, a window will list your imported information. Click the Finish button. Firefox will open.

4. Select whether you want Firefox to restore all or some windows and tabs and click the Let's go! button.
```

Comment: I have uninstalled firefox completely and reinstalled it again. Problem still there. But now issue is there only with firefox and particular wifi combination. Chrome work fine with same wifi and with different wifi all sites load perfectly.

Comment: I think refresh is more "powerful" than uninstalling. Refresh removes settings in firefox profile. Uninstall does not necessarily remove these settings.